# What is a "User Transaction" in the context of Microsoft SQL Server and Python's SQLAlchemy and pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Now I am doing something freaky here... I want to ingest data from a pandas dataframe into an in-memory OLTP database on Microsoft SQL Server 2019. The table is not existing yet and I want to create it on the fly based on the pandas dataframe.

For that, I modify the SQL create statement that pandas generates before it usually inserts data so that I will actually create the table as an in-memory table. The create statement works fine when used directly in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

However, when I use SQLAlchemy to run the create statement from within my Python script, I receive the following error message:

```
DDL statements ALTER, DROP and CREATE inside user transactions are not supported with memory optimized tables.
```

What does this mean? What is a user transaction? What could I try to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell unless we see the query used. This worked for me a few months ago, I am not next to sql to check `conn = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://Server_Name/Database_name?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
conn.execute('''
CREATE TABLE customer_table (
    CustomerKey   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    LastName      VARCHAR(250),
    BirthDate     DATE,
    ActiveStatus CHAR(3)
);
''')` can you share the code you're using

Comment: I just found out what the cause was... will post an answer. Thanks for taking the time to think about this

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the cause was due to the autocommit flag being set to False by default. After setting it to True, everything works as expected